# xorl %eax, %eax in x86_64 assembly code produced by gcc

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64

I'm a total noob at assembly, just poking around a bit to see what's going on.  Anyway, I wrote a very simple function:

```
void multA(double *x,long size)
{
  long i;
  for(i=0; i<size; ++i){
    x[i] = 2.4*x[i];
  }
}
```

I compiled it with:

```
gcc -S -m64 -O2 fun.c
```

And I get this:

```
    .file   "fun.c"
    .text
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  multA
    .type   multA, @function
multA:
.LFB34:
    .cfi_startproc
    testq   %rsi, %rsi
    jle .L1
    movsd   .LC0(%rip), %xmm1
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L3:
    movsd   (%rdi,%rax,8), %xmm0
    mulsd   %xmm1, %xmm0
    movsd   %xmm0, (%rdi,%rax,8)
    addq    $1, %rax
    cmpq    %rsi, %rax
    jne .L3
.L1:
    rep
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE34:
    .size   multA, .-multA
    .section    .rodata.cst8,"aM",@progbits,8
    .align 8
.LC0:
    .long   858993459
    .long   1073951539
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

The assembly output makes sense to me (mostly) except for the line `xorl %eax, %eax`.  From googling, I gather that the purpose of this is simply to set `%eax` to zero, which in this case corresponds to my iterator `long i;`.

However, unless I am mistaken, `%eax` is a 32-bit register.  So it seems to me that this should actually be `xorq %rax, %rax`, particularly since this is holding a 64-bit long int.  Moreover, further down in the code, it actually uses the 64-bit register `%rax` to do the iterating, which never gets initialized outside of `xorl %eax %eax`, which would seem to only zero out the lower 32 bits of the register.

Am I missing something?

Also, out of curiosity, why are there two `.long` constants there at the bottom?  The first one, `858993459` is equal to the double floating-point representation of `2.4` but I can't figure out what the second number is or why it is there.

Comment: What is `sizeof(long)` on your platform?

Comment: @KerrekSB Ah OK. I see, sorry.

Comment: @KerrekSB By the way, checking out that value, `1073951539` is the 32-bit IEEE-754 representation for `2.05`.

Comment: @H2CO3: Doubly weird because we're expecting a 64-bit float...

Comment: Both longs are part of the 64-bit float.

Comment: @KerrekSB Nah, I just fail at paying attention... may bad >.<

Comment: The canonical Q&A for [x86-64 implicit zero-extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-most-x64-instructions-zero-the-upper-part-of-a-32-bit-register).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I gather that the purpose of this is simply to set %eax to zero

Yes.

> which in this case corresponds to my iterator long i;.

No. Your `i` is uninitialized in the declaration. Strictly speaking, that operation corresponds to the `i = 0` expression in the for loop.

> However, unless I am mistaken, %eax is a 32-bit register. So it seems to me that this should actually be xorq %rax, %rax, particularly since this is holding a 64-bit long int.

But clearing the lower double word of the register clears the entire register. This is not intuitive, but it's implicit.

Comment: Thanks.  I figured that must be the case, but I couldn't find it documented anywhere.  Like I said, I'm a total noob.

Comment: Learned something new today, didn't know that clearing EAX would clear RAX. However, I'm wondering whether 'clearing the lower word' is the right way to put it, isn't the word size 64 bits on an AMD64 architecture?

Comment: @us2012 the usual definition of "word size" are simply ignored by Intel. A word is 16 bits, always. 32 = dword, 64 = qword.

Comment: @us2012 I'm not a great hardware hacker, so you may actually be right, but in my read (apart from picky C terminology which I don't always apply in general cases), byte = 1 byte or 8 bits, word = 2 bytes or 16 bits, double word = 4 bytes or 32 bits, quad word = 8 bytes or 64 bits.

Comment: @mrip No problem, as I've stated, this is not obvious, so this is a legitimate beginner question. (I rarely say this so be proud :P)

Comment: @us2012 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-most-x64-instructions-zero-the-upper-part-of-a-32-bit-register

Comment: @user529758  
I gather that the purpose of this is simply to set %eax to zero
Yes.

which in this case corresponds to my iterator long i;.
No. Your i is uninitialized in the declaration. Strictly speaking, that operation corresponds to the i = 0 expression in the for loop.

However, unless I am mistaken, %eax is a 32-bit register. So it seems to me that this should actually be xorq %rax, %rax, particularly since this is holding a 64-bit long int.
But clearing the lower double word of the register clears the entire register. This is not intuitive, but it's implicit.

why is it so?

Comment: @andrewFromNowhere https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-most-x64-instructions-zero-the-upper-part-of-a-32-bit-register

Answer (score 2):

Just to answer the second part: `.long` means 32 bit, and the two integral constants side-by-side form the IEEE-754 representation of the double 2.4:

```
Dec: 1073951539  858993459
Hex: 0x40033333 0x33333333

     400 3333333333333
     S+E Mantissa
```

The exponent is offset by 1023, so the actual exponent is 0x400 − 1023 = 1. The leading "one" in the mantissa is implied, so it's 2<sup>1</sup> × 0b1.001100110011... (You recognize this periodic expansion as 3/15, i.e. 0.2. Sure enough, 2 × 1.2 = 2.4.)

Comment: Aha.  Thanks.  That makes perfect sense.

Comment: Um okay. Because I don't pay attention to the type being `double`, which is 64 bits long. +1.

Comment: @H2CO3: You got it mostly right, but the size of the exponent should have tipped you off :-)