# Real Mode 32-bit registers

Tags: assembly, x86, 32-bit, 16-bit, real-mode

I'm writing some Real Mode code and using 32 bit registers to do so (using the 0x66 prefix).

I've been looking through Intel's manuals, and cannot find the information I am looking for.
See: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html (I have skimmed Volume 1 Chapters 1-7, as well as specific instructions from Volume 2)

Does Intel guarantee specific behavior for the following code in real mode code? Is it the same as protected mode code?

```
mov eax, <some constant>
mov ebx, <some constant>
add ax, bx ; Are the top bits of ax zero'd, sign extended or left?
mov ax, <some constant> ; Does this leave top 16bits unchanged?
; From what I can tell, the top 16bits are unchanged, but where is this documented?
```

Note: I am not after how **specific** implementations act (ie code that checks it -- unless every implementation has always acted the same), just where Intel has documented this behavior.

Related: [x86_64 registers rax/eax/ax/al overwriting full register contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455447/x86-64-registers-rax-eax-ax-al-overwriting-full-register-contents)

How this is different: This question relates specifically to Real Mode operation, and whether the observations from the linked question are valid in Real Mode.

Can anyone help me find where I can find this documented for real mode code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that 16-bit and 8-bit alternate register names only access their respective subparts is more or less documented in section 3.4.1 of [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual, Volume 1: Basic Architecture](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html):

> As shown in Figure 3-5, the lower 16 bits of the general-purpose registers map directly to 
>   the register set found in
>   the 8086 and Intel 286 processors and can be referenced with the names AX, BX, CX, DX, BP, SI, DI,
>   and SP. Each
>   of the lower two bytes of the EAX, EBX, ECX, and EDX registers can be referenced by the names
>   AH, BH, CH, and DH (high bytes) and AL, BL, CL, and DL (low bytes).

[image: Figure 3-5]

Since the documentation doesn't describe these alternate registers as accessing anything other than the indicated parts of the register, there's no reason to assume that they would. Also note that section 3.4.1 applies to all operating modes of the processor except 64-bit mode, so it includes real mode as well.

Section 3.4.1.1 covers what happens in 64-bit mode, which where the behaviour described in the post you linked comes from:

> When in 64-bit mode, operand size determines the number of valid bits in the destination general-purpose register:
>
> - 64-bit operands generate a 64-bit result in the destination general-purpose register.
> - 32-bit operands generate a 32-bit result, zero-extended to a 64-bit result in the destination general-purpose
>   register.
> - 8-bit and 16-bit operands generate an 8-bit or 16-bit result. The upper 56 bits or 48 bits (respectively) of the
>   destination general-purpose register are not modified by the operation. If the result of an 8-bit or 16-bit
>   operation is intended for 64-bit address calculation, explicitly sign-extend the register to the full 64-bits.

Notably the 8-bit and 16-bit alternate registers work the same way in 64-bit modes as they do in other modes.

Finally even though the processor won't be implicitly erasing the upper 16-bits of the registers when you don't expect it, you can't necessarily depend on the environment you're executing in to not do this. Under MS-DOS it wasn't always safe to use upper 16-bits of the 32-bit registers, because you never knew when some call, interrupt service routine or TSR would change them. The various calling conventions and interfaces only defined what 16-bit registers were preserved and modified, they rarely if ever mentioned what happened to the upper 16-bits.

Comment: I don't need to worry about my execution environment, as I don't have one.

Comment: Thanks, I actually skipped over the 64bit mode notes completely when I read this chapter, as I hadn't expected the behavior to be detailed there.

Comment: Strictly speaking the 64-bit section doesn't apply to real-mode. What happens to the upper 32 bits of the 64-bit register is undefined in real-mode. And unless you're writing your own BIOS firmware or equivalent, you still might have to worry about other code trashing the 32-bit registers.

Answer (score 0):

Contents of the top 16 bits are left unchanged. There are separate instructions for zero extension ([MOVZX](http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/movzx.htm)) and for sign extension ([MOVSX](http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/movsx.htm)). I am sure that it's documented somewhere that ax refers to lower 16 bits of the eax register and in that case the zero extension would be "non-default" behavior like in the x86_64. This behavior is also clearly stated in the x86_64 documentation.

Comment: "I am sure that it's documented somewhere" -- this is what the question is asking -- where?

Comment: @James I thought you were asking where is it documented that zero/sign extension does or does not happen and I am saying that it probably isn't documented at all because there is no reason to think it should happen. But the fact that ax is part of eax is documented "somewhere" :)