# Understanding the un-optimized asm for C that dereferences an uninitialized pointer, causing a segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, assembly

I set a experiment to see whether it works or not

```
int *p;
p[0] = 3;
```

My idea is that the compiler gives a random value to p and I can consider it as a array.

But it turns out segmentation fault and I don't understand the assembly code.

```
   0x0000000000401530 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000000401531 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000401534 <+4>: sub    $0x30,%rsp
   0x0000000000401538 <+8>: mov    %ecx,0x10(%rbp)
   0x000000000040153b <+11>:    mov    %rdx,0x18(%rbp)
   0x000000000040153f <+15>:    callq  0x402170 <__main>
   0x0000000000401544 <+20>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
=> 0x0000000000401548 <+24>:    movl   $0x3,(%rax)
   0x000000000040154e <+30>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000401553 <+35>:    add    $0x30,%rsp
   0x0000000000401557 <+39>:    pop    %rbp
   0x0000000000401558 <+40>:    retq
```

I searched on google, mov is Intel style and movl is AT&T style. How come these two style come together?

At this line:

```
mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
```

It seems like move the value of address rbp-0x8 to register rax, right?
Is this "-0x8(%rbp)" a random value goes to p?

I think %rax is not p, because at next line CPU give $0x3 to %rax. It seems the %rax is the first memory of the array.

How do I interpret this assembly code? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. Why move 32-bit value 3 to register rax is a segmentation fault?

Comment: Because it tries to move an immediate value to some address that your program doesn't have access to.

Comment: @iBug: AT&T syntax only requires an operand-size suffix when it's ambiguous (like with an immediate source and memory destination).  `mov $0, %eax` is 32-bit operand-size, implied by the EAX register.  Plain `mov` doesn't imply 16-bit in any way.  This disassembly is only using suffixes where it's ambiguous, unlike `objdump -d` which uses a suffix on every instruction.  (@ Andy: the entire listing is pure AT&T syntax, always with the destination on the right).

Comment: @PeterCordes Do you mean that `movl $0x3,(%rax)` would otherwise mean the 64-bit MOV instruction if it wasn't spelled `movl`?

Comment: @iBug: no, it would be an error: put it into `bar.S` and assemble it with `gcc -c bar.S`, and you'll get this assembler error message `bar.S:1: Error: no instruction mnemonic suffix given and no register operands; can't size instruction`.  i.e. the operand-size is ambiguous, so the assembler refused to assemble it.

Comment: @iBug `mov` is not necessarily a 16 bit operation! `movw` is the 16 bit `mov`, a `mov` without suffix moves as many bits as demanded by its operands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert at assembly, but the code looks quite clear so I'll give it an attempt to explain it.

---

```
   0x0000000000401530 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000000401531 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
```

(Above) This is some "procedural" code that the compiler generates when optimization is not turned on. It saves the state of RSP (64-bit stack pointer).

```
   0x0000000000401534 <+4>: sub    $0x30,%rsp
```

This reserves extra space on the stack for local variables.

```
   0x0000000000401538 <+8>: mov    %ecx,0x10(%rbp)
   0x000000000040153b <+11>:    mov    %rdx,0x18(%rbp)
```

This saves argc and argv onto the stack, because you made a debug build so all variables have to be in memory.  (The space it's using is above the return address, where `main`'s caller reserved space.  This is called shadow space, and is a feature of the Windows x64 calling convention.)

```
   0x000000000040153f <+15>:    callq  0x402170 <__main>
```

This calls some kind of early init function.  It might use argc and argv (still in registers), or it might not; we can't tell from the code.

```
   0x0000000000401544 <+20>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
```

This loads uninitialized stack memory as the value of `int *p`.  Automatic variables are placed on stack.  You read `p` without having written it first, and the compiler just reads whatever garbage or zeros were already in the stack slot it chose for `int *p;`

```
=> 0x0000000000401548 <+24>:    movl   $0x3,(%rax)
```

This line sets the address that `rax` points to to immediate value 3.

The value of `p` is in `rax`, so this is your `p[0] = 3;`, dereferencing whatever garbage `p` holds.  You crash because it's doesn't happen to point to writeable memory.  (Overwriting some random dword in memory would hardly be better, but at least your code wouldn't crash *here*, just maybe at some point later, if the garbage value of `p` happened to be a valid pointer.)

```
   0x000000000040154e <+30>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
```

This sets the register `eax` to zero, and [effectively setting `rax` to zero, too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25455447/5958455).  Windows x64 (like every standard calling convention) uses RAX for return values, so this is implementing the implicit `return 0;` at the bottom of `main`.

```
   0x0000000000401553 <+35>:    add    $0x30,%rsp
   0x0000000000401557 <+39>:    pop    %rbp
   0x0000000000401558 <+40>:    retq
```

Restores the pointer states to before the function call.

Comment: The instructions before the `call __main` aren't "preparing" for it, they're just saving `main`'s function args on the stack. (Which the x64 Windows calling convention passes in RCX=argc, RDX=argv).  Actually it's just spilling them on function entry (into the shadow space above the return address) because it's a debug build; it doesn't reload them later.  We can't tell whether `__main` actually takes any args or not, because `main`'s args are still in the arg-passing registers when it's called.  We can't tell if `__main` looks at them or not.

Comment: I didn't want to take the time to write my own answer, so I made a substantial edit to yours.  The explanations are now expert-approved. :)  You were mostly close before, including getting the exact cause of the problem correct, but I split up the code before `call __main` into more separate blocks because they're unrelated.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks, expert at assembly. I think I've got a better understanding, too.

Comment: @iBug Hi. Could you please tell me which part of this question can be improved with a prerequisite of not editting the context? I want downvote removed.